# How to simulate Network situation where message lost or server don't send it?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, message

I've wrote simple Client-Server application and try to test it.

I need to write some code to handle when the reply message (sent by server) is being lost and don't reach the client ...

I need to know how to simulate such situation. but I cannot.

I've tried the `CTRL-C` the server .. but not sure if this a good scenario..
I got from the client:

```
send:
0 0 0 5 0 0 1 48 25 112 -55 106 0 0 0 34 60 -72 117 -101 37 28 116 -85 -91 61 55
 -126 -50 9 5 64 -87 126 -31 -62 30 13 -90 -72 -124 118 20 88 -80 -9 -36 -33 -38
 123

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at net.Net.readMessageObject(Net.java:36)
        at net.Pitcher.run(Pitcher.java:59)
        at net.Pitcher.main(Pitcher.java:122)
```

BTW, the app written in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is rather simple you can use a programm like netcat to connect to it, dont send anything at some point and see what happens.
Otherwise what you could do is rewrite your server app a little bit to introduce some sort of random fails for testing.

Comment: Judging from your code, you're using TCP, is that right? Because in TCP packets cant get lost. The TCP-Protocol ensures that the packets dont get malformed, lost or out of order. If you want to make sure your application doesn't break if the connection is lost completely, Ctrl+C'ing the server is actually a reasonable scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but what about a timeout for example?

Comment: What do you mean by "timeout"?
The server crashed: this will reset the connection like Ctrl+C.
You cannot even connect to the server: this is like not even running the server side.
The server doesnt respond with anything: just comment all the answer and handling part from your server and run it.
These are pretty much the only scenarios of what could happen to the connection/server. Everything else is handled by the TCP-Protocol already (like you cant lose packets or something).

Comment: I did the following at the server: for every 4 message, don't send the response for the 5th request.. and at client I used `socket.setSoTimeout(500)`. so the client wait5 500ms for the message and then it mark it as lost (and most importantly remove the IO block of the `outputStream.read()` method ) and continue sending the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mock network object, so you can simulate various situations, in each case manipulating the mock network object so that you can test that your application interacts with it appropriately.